# Ugly optimized caching of SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, optimization, multithreading, datetime, cache

Concerning the optimization of this simple function

```
String formatDate(String format, Locale locale, Date date) {...}
```

formatting a `Date` using a `SimpleDateFormat` created with the arguments `format` and `locale`. I'm curious  what you thing about the code below. I know it's terrible, but let's assume two things

1. The code must be as fast as possible.
2. There's no suitable object to hold the cache.
3. It must not cause any memory leaks.

Because of 1., a thread local [cache should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/817926/581205) be used. However, the passed format and arguments may differ from those used in the cache and this must be checked. Funnily, although `SimpleDateFormat` is mutable (which is the cause of all problems), there seem to be no way how to change its `format` or `locale`. Actually, the parameters hardly ever change, but there's no guarantee.

Because of 2., the cache must be a static field.

Because of 3., no `ThreadLocal.initialValue` can be used as it'd lead to memory leaks just like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19642687/581205). For the same reason no custom class may be put into the `ThreadLocal`.

This all is pretty restrictive. So I wrote the following ugliness

```
private String toString(Date obj, String format, Locale locale) {
    return getSimpleDateFormat(format, locale).format(obj);
}

private SimpleDateFormat getSimpleDateFormat(String format, Locale locale) {
    Object[] list = SDF.get();
    // An identity check is faster and correct as missing an entry is allowed.
    // It's surely good enough as passing equals but not same parameters hardly ever happens.
    if (list!=null && list[0] == format && list[1] == locale) {
        return (SimpleDateFormat) list[2];
    }
    final SimpleDateFormat result = new SimpleDateFormat(format, locale);
    list = new Object[] {format, locale, result};
    SDF.set(list);
    return result;
}

/** Contains triples (String format, Locale locale, SimpleDateFormat sdf) */
private static final ThreadLocal<Object[]> SDF = new ThreadLocal<Object[]>();
```

I don't care about naming and such, as this was just a quick implementation of an idea. I'm curious if there's a substantially better solution satisfying all the above conditions.

<sup>If you say, it's premature optimization, I'll fully agree, but let's assume for a while it must be done. If you say, that's hardly faster than no caching, then show me your figures.</sup>

---

Obviously, I'm caching just one value per thread. It should be enough in many cases like producing a CSV with one one or more dates per row as I haven't yet see them to be formatted differently.

However, time is "date" too (at least in Java), and a CSV line containing both date and time in separate columns is rather common and this would render my poor man's cache fully ineffective.

Comment: Just checking… the standard formats available through [`DateFormat.getDateInstance(style, locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance%28int,%20java.util.Locale%29) aren't good enough for you?

Comment: @200_success Actually, it started as an idea to things like `format("Drink %d beers on %[yy-mm-dd]", 6, tomorrow)`, so there's no use for the standard instance. While supporting those standard formats makes sense, too, I'd bet they suffer from the same problem and you need some TL caching, too. I guess, I should benchmark it.

Comment: Formatting date isn't a complicated task, have you considered writing your own formatter, which will do the task on the fly?

Comment: @ekaerovets No, it's simple when done for English, but I'd like to provide the full functionality. I know, there's `FastDateFormat` by Apache, but I didn't want to include another dependency. It's not really important... but I'm curious if there's a nicer way.

Comment: It seems strange to cache only one instance per thread. If a block of code needs to format multiple dates using the same format and locale--the only case where you'll get a cache hit--it should keep a local copy.

Comment: @DavidHarkness IMHO the typical case is like writing a CSV containing one or more dates per row.. and you hardly ever want to format them differently. But what can happen is dates and times in one row... and then I'd lose (or fallback to a normal cache). I forgot about time being a date. :D

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by *'must not cause any memory leaks'*?

Comment: @rolfl I mean memory leaks when your application gets undeployed from a webserver [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642687/critical-guava-memory-leak-workaround-needed). Putting any instance of any non-JDK class in a `ThreadLocal` causes this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did in the end. As pointed by others, my single element cache would be totally ineffective if multiple formats would be used in an interleaved fashion (formatting a date differently is probably rare, but using both date and time is rather common).

There's a [LoadingCache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html) in Guava, so I went for it. It needs a composed key, so I created a tiny class and used [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) so I didn't go mad when writing all the boring stuff.

As the stupid class (just in case it's unclear, I mean `SimpleDateFormat`) is documented to be thread-unsafe, the same `SimpleDateFormat` mustn't be handled to different threads. So my `CacheKey` contains the thread id as well. I'd bet, this is simpler and faster than putting a `Cache` into a `ThreadLocal` or the other way round.

```
final class DateHelper2 {
    @RequiredArgsConstructor @EqualsAndHashCode
    private static final class CacheKey {
        private final Thread thread;
        private final String format;
        private final Locale locale;
    }

    static String format(String format, Locale locale, Date date) {
        return get(format, locale).format(date);
    }

    private static SimpleDateFormat get(String format, Locale locale) {
        CacheKey cacheKey = new CacheKey(Thread.currentThread(), format, locale);
        return loadingCache.getUnchecked(cacheKey);
    }

    private static final LoadingCache<CacheKey, SimpleDateFormat> loadingCache =
            CacheBuilder
            .newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .build(new CacheLoader<CacheKey, SimpleDateFormat>() {
                @Override public SimpleDateFormat load(CacheKey key) {
                    return new SimpleDateFormat(key.format, key.locale);
                }
            });
}
```

## Is it worth the effort?

Surely, using `FastDateFormat` would be much easier, but let's assume it doesn't exists. I ran a single-threaded benchmark with a one (right) or two (left) SDFs
and got mostly expected results:

[image: results]

The red bars are for no caching at all, while the green ones corresponds with manually creating the SDF before the loop. You can see that there's nearly a factor of 4 between them. The solution from this answer is in yellow, not very far from the optimum. In case a single SDF is needed, the approach from my question is even better (blue).

---

There's also a funny method in SDF

```
StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition)
```

which should be faster, and it usually is, but only a bit and not always. The magenta bars show an inexplicable factor 2 slowdown, when it gets used together with Guava's cache. So I'd suggest to forget about `StringBuffer` and related methods.

#### Update

First I was using threadId, but this makes little sense, as `Thread::getId()` is not `final`. Edited to using `Thread` directly.

Answer (score 3):

What about using a [`WeakHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html)?  The memory leak is not really an issue since the memory can be reclaimed at any time.

Also, if I were using a map, I would define a `FormatAndLocale` util class, with valid `hashCode` and `equals`, to be used as keys.

Comment: And what about thread safety? Do you mean combined with `ThreadLocal`? If so, please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, I meant like you are doing, but using a WeakHashMap instead of only caching one value.  I believe weak references were introduced for caching, just like you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Your above solution seems to be violating your 3rd requirement.

> 3. It must not cause any memory leaks.

How are you cleaning the cache when the thread dies.

Also your approach is more like ThreadLocal only but with the added contention of LocadingCache and no GC (because you don't really know when any thread dies).

If your server provides a method which is invoked when the app is undeployed, see if you can use the same to your advantage.

Comment: When the thread dies, [everything is fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3869236/581205). Don't blame me for [leaks created by a webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19692413/581205). There may be a sort of memory leak, but just a very tiny one; not the whole app as usual with webservers, it's just a few bytes, as all the classes used belong to the boot classloader. The Cache is designed to work with multiple threads well. Unlike my TL approach, the Cache works even when multiple formats are needed (like in "format date, format time, format date, format time, ....").

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a simple synchronized Map:

```
private static final Map<String, Map<Locale, SimpleDateFormat>> cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Map<Locale, SimpleDateFormat>>());

public static String formatDateDefault(String format, Locale locale, Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, locale);
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

public static String formatDateCached(String format, Locale locale, Date date) {
    
    Map<Locale, SimpleDateFormat> map = cache.get(format);
    if (map == null) {
        cache.put(format, map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Locale, SimpleDateFormat>()));
    }
    
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = map.get(locale);
    
    if (dateFormat == null) {
        map.put(locale, dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, locale));
    }
    
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String[] formats = { "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yy", "dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS", "dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS Z" };
    Locale[] locales = { Locale.CANADA, Locale.GERMANY, Locale.FRANCE, Locale.ITALY };
    long s, e;
    Random r = new Random();
    int maxIterations       = 1_000_000;
    int maxWarmUPIterations = 10_000;
    
    // WARMUP
    for (int i = 0; i < maxWarmUPIterations; i++) {
        formatDateDefault(formats[i % formats.length], locales[i % locales.length], new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < maxWarmUPIterations; i++) {
        formatDateCached(formats[i % formats.length], locales[i % locales.length], new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
    }
    
    // GO!!!
    s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
        formatDateDefault(formats[i % formats.length], locales[i % locales.length], new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
    }
    
    e = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    System.out.println((e - s) + " ms.");
    
    s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
        formatDateCached(formats[i % formats.length], locales[i % locales.length], new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE)));
    }
    
    e = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
    System.out.println((e - s) + " ms.");
}
```

Output:

> 4484 ms.
>
> 1478 ms.

Comment: The synchronization may or may not help, as it still allows two different threads to use the same SDF at the same time. This may work, or not, depending on what way the SDF is unsafe.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe. So while you're safely managing the *collection* of formatters, you're allowing multiple threads to access the same instance which is unsafe. Thus the use of `ThreadLocal` to segregate the instances.

Comment: By inspecting the code of `SimpleDateFormat` we might find out that it's thread-safe w.r.t. to using it with the same format and locale and changing the date only. But for sure, we'd see that it's pretty terrible piece of code. Besides avoiding SDF, the best solutions seems to be mine (3-part cache key).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use LinkedHashMap instead of ThreadLocals and WeakReferences.

```
    private static final Integer MAX_ENTRIES = new Integer(30);

private static final Map<Long, SimpleDateFormat> CACHE = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<Long, SimpleDateFormat>(MAX_ENTRIES + 1, 0.75F, true) {
    @Override protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<Long, SimpleDateFormat> eldest) {
        return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
    }
});

private String toString(Date obj, String format, Locale locale) {
    return getSimpleDateFormat(format, locale).format(obj);
}

private SimpleDateFormat getSimpleDateFormat(String format, Locale locale) {
    Long id = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(format.hashCode()) + Math.abs(locale.hashCode()));

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = CACHE.get(id);
    if (sdf == null) {
        synchronized (MAX_ENTRIES) {
            sdf = CACHE.get(id);

            if (sdf == null) {
                sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, locale);

                CACHE.put(id, sdf);
            }
        }
    }

    return sdf.clone();
}
```

Comment: You're synchronizing the cache, but you hand out the `SimpleDateFormat` to multiple threads. Funnily, you're synchronizing on a public object (the autoboxed 30 comes from [`Integer.cache`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.IntegerCache.0cache).